# Convert permission array to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm trying to implement Role Based Access control in my nestjs project and I have a permission array as follows

```html
let permissions = [
            "newsfeeds-alerts-view",
            "settings-group_details-view",
            "settings-group_details-edit",
            "settings-privileges-view",
            "settings-privileges-edit",
            "settings-my_groups-create",
            "settings-my_groups-view",
            "settings-my_groups-edit",
            "settings-my_groups-delete",
            "settings-users-view",
            "settings-users-edit",
            "settings-users-delete",
            "notifications-email-create",
            "notifications-jira-create",
            "notifications-jira-view",
            "notifications-non_itr_ticket-create",
            "notifications-non_itr_ticket-update",
            "workspace_dashboard-worksapce-create",
            "workspace_dashboard-worksapce-view",
            "dashboard-geographic-maps-view",
            "dashboard-geographic-report-itr-view",
            "configurations-create_alerts-create",
            "configurations-notifications-jira-create"
];
```

I want to create a JSON string from the above array as follows

```html
{
  "newsfeeds": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "name": "view"
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "group_details": [
      {
        "name": "view"
      },
      {
        "name": "edit"
      }
    ],
    "privileges": [
      {
        "name": "view"
      },
      {
        "name": "edit"
      }
    ],
    "my_groups": [
      {
        "name": "view"
      },
      {
        "name": "edit"
      },
      {
        "name": "delete"
      }
    ],
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "view"
      },
      {
        "name": "edit"
      },
      {
        "name": "delete"
      }
    ]
  },
  "notifications": {
    "email": [
      {
        "name": "create"
      }
    ],
    "jira": [
      {
        "name": "create"
      },
      {
        "name": "view"
      }
    ],
    "non_itr_ticket": [
      {
        "name": "create"
      },
      {
        "name": "update"
      }
    ]
  },
  "workspace_dashboard": {
    "worksapce": [
      {
        "name": "create"
      },
      {
        "name": "view"
      }
    ]
  },
  "dashboard": {
    "geographic": {
      "maps": [
        {
          "name": "view"
        }
      ],
      "report": {
        "itr": [
          {
            "name": "view"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "configurations": {
      "create_alerts": [
        {
          "name": "create"
        }
      ],
      "notifications": {
        "jira": [
          {
            "name": "create"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The permission array is dynamic. I need to group all common permission under one object.

How to achieve this, any easy methods available ?

Comment: well, first create a javscript object in the right format, then use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON

Comment: `create a JSON object` ... you can't ... JSON is simply a string representation of data, it's a string, there's no `JSON object`

Comment: @Bravo any suggestion on the logic to create the JavaScript object

Comment: yep, split the strings on `-` and go from there with a reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array.reduce` `string.split` to achieve your desired result

```js
let permissions = ["newsfeeds-alerts-view","settings-group_details-view","settings-group_details-edit","settings-privileges-view","settings-privileges-edit","settings-my_groups-create","settings-my_groups-view","settings-my_groups-edit","settings-my_groups-delete","settings-users-view","settings-users-edit","settings-users-delete","notifications-email-create","notifications-jira-create","notifications-jira-view","notifications-non_itr_ticket-create","notifications-non_itr_ticket-update","workspace_dashboard-worksapce-create","workspace_dashboard-worksapce-view","dashboard-geographic-maps-view","dashboard-geographic-report-itr-view","configurations-create_alerts-create","configurations-notifications-jira-create",];


const output = permissions.reduce((r, s) => {
    const path = s.split("-");
    if (path.length > 1) {
        const name = path.pop();
        const last = path.pop();
        let destination = r;
        for (let key of path) {
            destination[key] = destination[key] || {};
            destination = destination[key];
        }
        destination[last] = destination[last] || [];
        destination[last].push({ name });
    }
    return r;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bravo this answer is working for my case.

Comment: Yes, @AbhilashShajan - I did check that the result was what you expected - even though your example missed at least one "name", I figured that was because you had to manually "convert" and you simply skipped one line of the input

Answer (score 0):

```ts
let obj: any = {}

permissions.forEach(permission => {
    const [category, subcategory, name] = permission.split('-')
    if (!obj[category]) {
        obj[category] = {}
    }
    if (!obj[category][subcategory]) {
        obj[category][subcategory] = []
    }
    obj[category][subcategory].push({ name })
})

let json = JSON.stringify(obj) // there you go
```

Comment: that's a naive way of course, it assumes the `.split` results in exactly 3 items - not that it's bad, it's infinitely better than what the OP did ... i.e. nothing at all

Comment: did you test your code? how does it deal with `dashboard-geographic-report-itr-view` for example? hint: it fails

Comment: Thanks @RuiSiang for your answer, Here the logic is expecting only 3 items on .split, how can I handle multiple. In my case `dashboard-geographic-report-itr-view` gives five items on split. So here it will fail. Any suggestion to handle such cases ?

Comment: @AbhilashShajan write your own code based on this as a start ...